# Call method in object by property dynamically

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a component that receives some parameters and needs to **call functions that are provided in params**. the problem is functions are dynamic so I need to define them before sending them.

here is the parameter that can be pass to the component

```
export class SomeConfig {
 baseScope: any;
 functions?: { buttonName: string, buttonEvent: string, buttonFunction: Function}[]
}
```

This is how I fill the parameter and pass it to the component. as you see I can define the functions that I want by filling the **buttonFunction** property.

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
   this.gridconfig = {
       baseScope : this,
       functions: [
         { buttonName: 'data-edit', buttonEvent: 'click', buttonFunction: this.edit},
         { buttonName: 'data-del', buttonEvent: 'hover', buttonFunction: this.delete},
       ]
    };
  });
 }

edit(){
}

delete(){
}
```

now I have both the mainScope and the function. **I want to find the method in the mainScope**.

```
this.someconfigs.functions.forEach(fnc => {
//here i have fnc.buttonFunction which defined before and exists in this.someconfigs.mainScope
//i need to find fnc.buttonFunction in mainScope and called it dynamically, for example calling edit 
})
```

currently, I'm using the following syntax.I pass the scope to the function

```
fnc.buttonFunction(this.someconfigs.baseScope);
```

And in my function I have a parameter to use the main scope

```
edit(scope: any) {
//instead of this.someproperties I use scope.someproperties  I want to call it directly in order to remove passing scope parameter
console.log("called");
}
```

I want to call it directly in order to remove the passing scope parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Function.prototype.bind`

```
edit() {
  console.log("called");
  console.log(this.someproperties);
}


fnc.buttonFunction.bind(this)();
```

Or just bind the scope when declaring the functions:

```
{
  buttonName: 'data-del',
  buttonEvent: 'hover',
  buttonFunction: this.delete.bind(this),
},
```

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I was looking for. I just wondering is it possible to find a function in the object?

Comment: Find how exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You can just call it like any other function, given that your `fnc` object holds the property and its a callable function

```
this.someconfigs.functions.forEach(fnc => {
  // just call it
  fnc.buttonFunction();
})
```

Comment: if I call fnc.buttonFunction directly I don't have access this keyword.I need the main scope

Comment: Mhm, given you're using arrow-functions the binding should be correct. What's the exact error that pops up?

Comment: That is the problem with this approach.. scope. I would reconsider. Else, bind ‘this’ where you still have access to it.

Comment: The correct "angular" way would be to work with `@Output` I assume. Maybe that's an option for you?

Comment: @PhilippMeissner Yes. but we are using a jquery library that we don't want to rewrite again. I have the function and scope just looking to find a way to find a method in the object.

Comment: @PhilippMeissner in using arrow-functions fnc do nothing with the main scope so if I call buttonFunction i need to pass the main scope